# Kafka globaltable local state

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

When we get data using key as input in globaltable kafka consumer.
What happened when local store had duplicate key in that case which record is provided by get().

Answer (score 1):

A local store cannot have several entries with the same key.

When a key-value message is consumed:

- If the store does not contain the key yet, the key and value are simply added;
- If the store already contains the key, the previous value is replaced with the new one.

The `get` will always return the most recently consumed value for the key.